# change logfile name dynamically in app.config

Tags: c#

I have a C# program written that uses the below logFile for logging.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="logFile" value="D:\logs\MyProgramLog.txt"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>


static class LoggingClass
    {
         public static void info(string messString)
        {
            try
            {
                //show log on console
                 Console.WriteLine(messString);

                //write log to log file
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logFile"].ToString(), true))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("info: " + messString);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
             }
        }
}

 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoggingClass.info("Started Program run at" +DateTime.Now);
}
```

Every time the logfile name is MyProgramLog.txt.
How can I change logFile name to be MyProgramLog_2015_02_13.txt dynamically i.e append the date to the logfile name in app.config file?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe existing solutions like NLog will suit your needs?

Comment: @Alex K, Very simple. Just trying to find out when a program started ended when it's run each day. We are having some issues on the server i am running. DBA wants to know the average time my program takes to run. So, I want to create this log file.

Comment: Well, I would still recommend to use NLog. It can create each day a new log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code you are looking for:

```
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(logFile);
var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(configFile);
var todayFileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyy_MM_dd");
var ext = Path.GetExtension(configFile);
var newLogFile = path + todayFileName + ext;
```